# SSH doesn't work after installing MS Hololens Emulator

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, hyper-v, hololens, hololens-emulator

We have powerful PC with Win10 for developing AR Applications with MS Hololens Emulator. It has Cygwin installed with ssh server package what is running in the default configuration, e.g. listening on port 22 for ssh.

However the PC is a workingstation for every employee so if you want to versionate work you have done with your own credentials on the PC we tunnel with our MacBooks via

```
ssh -A xoxo@blabla
```

to the PC and do your git stuff.

Now I started developing for the MS Hololens on the PC.

I followed the instructions from the [Windows Developer site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/install_the_tools) to get started and everything works fine.

SSH worked fine before installing the Emulator.

And now the !!!BIG BUT!!!: Somehow I can't ssh to the PC anymore from my MacBook. It seems that installing the Hololens Emulator changed something with the network/settings, I suspect changing the ssh ports or something.

My co-worker who hasn't installed the Emulator but develops for the Hololens as well hasn't faced any issues, so my guess is that installing the Emulator VM with the Hyper-V has changed something.

1. The error was

   `ssh: Could not resolve hostname blabla: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

   But the hostname was 100% correct.
2. I added the public key to the known_hosts manually. And now It can resolve the hostname and of course asks for the password of the PC, but if I type it in, it won't let me pass eventough its written down:

   `ssh -A xoxo@blabla
   xoxo@blabla's password: 
   Permission denied, please try again.`

Has anyone mentioned something similar and/or has a guess, why it asks me for blabla's password, but won't take it, is maybe some VM service pushing in front of the normal login?

Thank you very much, Khaled.

Comment: "Somehow I can't ssh to the PC anymore from my MacBook." Please [edit] your question to describe in detail how the ssh server is set up on this system and what happens when you try to ssh into it. You've given absolutely no details here.

Comment: Okay, I tried to explain more briefly what I have done and what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

For everyone who might run into the same problem.

If you use Microsoft Visual Studio Professional, it comes with to Services which activate automatically on starting your computer.

- SSH Server Proxy
- SSH Server Broker

What solved my the problem:

1. Go to "services" via Win+R -> type in services.msc
2. Search for the service SSH Server Proxy -> right-click it -> preferences -> Starttype: dropdown -> Select "deactivated"
3. Click on apply.
4. Same for the service SSH Server Broker
5. Restart PC.

Now you are able to tunnel to your PC again via SSH. :)